# how to get leader identity with azure blob storage?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I'm trying to use azure blob storage to do leader election, and I can manage to get leader elected and followers standby.

like

```
resp,err:=blob.AquireLease(....)

if err==nil{
    println("leader get lease",resp.LeaseId())

}else{
    println("followers")
}
//TODO: followers don't know ipaddress of leader
```

But I need followers to be able to get leader's IpAddress (identity), how could I achieve it?

The only approach I can think of is letting leader write its identity to blob and followers read it then.

```
if leader {
    ip=...
    blob.upload(ip,...)
}else{
    resp,_:=blob.download(...)
    leaderIp:=getip(resp)
    println("leader ip ",leaderIp)
}
```

But since the operation is not atomic and might lead to inconsistent issues (some followers might get staled leader identity).

Tried redis, it works fine to aquirelease and get current leader identity in one transaction